# Service Cloud Console Subtab - lookup field and output link

Tags: visualforce, servicecloud, service-cloud-console

There are 2 scenarios here -

1. There is a custom lookup field on the case object, on click of the lookup - I need to open the record in the subtab. Is this possible?
2. There are couple of output links (inline visualforce on the account detail page) - I need to open the record (output link is lookup to some other object record) in the subtab.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

For 1, in VisualForce see the same concept as 2 below, otherwise for standard layout you can set the way it opens under Setup->Create->App->your app->Edit->Choose How Records Display.

You can configure how each relationship opens up either as a separate primary tab or a subtab of a specific related object (or the current case itself).

[image]

**Edit** Per the comments you said it is in standard layout and actually a formula field.  I don't know of any way of forcing a formula field to open in subtab, but you can do this with a detail custom link.

This will allow you to make a link on the standard layout that opens a subtab.  To do so create a detail custom link with the behavior set to "Execute Javascript".  Inside the javascript use the function srcUp like this (example opens Account in a sub tab):

```
srcUp('{!URLFOR($Action.MyCustomObject__c.View,Case.MyLookupToCustomObjId__c)}');
```

You can learn more about the srcUp feature here in a blog post from one of the PMs of the Service Cloud, Gautam Vasudev:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YKxYAAW

For item 2 in VisualForce you can accomplish it with the console toolkit API.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/index.htm

Here is an example of opening a subtab from an outputLink (note: requires a remote access for google.com setup in your org.  Change the url to something else for your own testing purposes).

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/22.0/integration.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openSubTab(url,label,name,openimmediately) {
  sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function(primarytab){
    sforce.console.openSubtab(primarytab.id , url, openimmediately, label, null, function(result){
      // do any processing here if passes or fails, use result.success (boolean)
    }, name);
  });
}
</script>
<apex:outputLink value="#" onclick="openSubTab('http://www.google.com','google','googleSubTab',true);return false;">Open Google SubTab</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: for the first point, a bit of correction. It is actually not a lookup, but a formula field.

Comment: Is it being displayed on a VisualForce page or standard layout page?

Comment: displayed as a standard page layout !!

Comment: @RoshanSahatiya - added some info for you.  I recommend a custom link if you can use that instead.  I'm not aware of a way to get a formula field to function as you need.

Answer (score 0):

This works for Salesforce Classic and Console in my org (Unlimited Edition).

Custom Field, Formula, takes a DATE/Time field and makes it a hyperlink.

```
HYPERLINK("javascript:if(typeof(srcUp)=='function') srcUp('/" & Id & "?isdtp=vw'); "+
"else {window.open('/" & Id & " ' )}",
TEXT( MONTH( DATEVALUE( Date_Time__c ) ) ) +
"/" +
TEXT( DAY( DATEVALUE( Date_Time__c ) ) ) +
"/" +
TEXT( YEAR( DATEVALUE( Date_Time__c ) ) ) +
" @ " +
TEXT ( VALUE( MID( TEXT( CreatedDate -5/24 ), 12, 2 ) ) ) +
":" +
TEXT ( VALUE( MID( TEXT( Date_Time__c -5/24 ), 15, 2 ) ) ), "_parent")
```